# Magento 2: Unable to run setup:di:compile

Tags: magento2, setup-di-compile

Ran into this error when running `setup:di:compile` after `composer install`

```
 [RuntimeException]                                                                                                                             
  Source class "\Zend\Mvc\Controller\LazyControllerAbstract" for "Zend\Mvc\Controller\LazyControllerAbstractFactory" generation does not exist.
```

Any ideas how to fix or debug this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento official document has written the good guide on this, do check it out! I hope it will be helpful for you.

That's the error cause mentioned by Magento in their guide:

"The error occurs because the **setup:di:compile** command tries to access the var/di and var/generation directories, which are read-only.

It is not a defect but an expected behavior on cloud environments. You should not run **setup:di:compile** manually since this command is being executed during the deployment process. The Magento code cannot be changed on the fly (because it is located in the read-only directories), so there is no need to recompile var/di and var/generation: there is no difference with files generated during deployment."

For further read: https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002663433-Error-running-the-setup-di-compile-command-manually

Comment: that was exactly the problem, thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad to hear that!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a module is extending the block incorrectly. Do you have anything custom you were working on in /code?

Comment: yeah there are a few custom modules, but i don't know how or where to start to debug this

Comment: First run search thru the code in app/code for LazyControllerAbstract keyword